# Project Migration from VS2013 to VS2015 causing Azure rendering issues

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure

I recently started a project in VS 2013, then upgraded my IDE to VS 2015 where I continued the project.  Its an ASP.Net MVC5 project.  The only thing I had to really modify as far as I could tell was to change the data source localDb v11 to MSSQLLocalDB for local development.

However, prior to moving the project into VS2015, I was able to publish to Azure for testing where the project rendered correctly like it does now when I run it locally.  Since  I moved to VS2015, when I publish to Azure, the site no longer renders correctly.  The stylesheets are not being applied in some cases.

Has anyone had this issue?  Are there other changes I need to make to the project?  I'm using code first with migrations and I've even deleted the website and db on azure and recreated but I still have the same issue.

Updates to the bundler?

Comment: what does "no longer renders correctly" actually mean? are you getting errors? is it rendering but the styles are off? is it rendering with different data than you expect, or a different page than you expect?  Your question isn't answerable with the information you provided.

Comment: sorry, updated for further clarification

Comment: I doubt that the stylesheets not being applied has anything to do with changing the Visual Studio version, but I could be wrong.....  First things first, have you checked the network tab in the browser console to see if there are any files that can't be loaded for some reason?

Comment: maybe old css file have been cached? try a hard refresh (F5 usually) of the browser

Comment: @claires thanks for the tip.  Its not loading a css resource.  Now I just have to figure out which resource because the bundle.Config file encrypts the file name.  its strange that I don't have this issue when I build locally though.